# RREF and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i \end{pmatrix}$ and $\det(A) = 1$. What does that tell us about the $\text{RREF}$ of the matrix

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c&\lambda_1\\d&e&f&\lambda_2\\g&h&i&\lambda_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

In particular, is the $\text{RREF}$ of $B$ such that the non-$\lambda$ columns (essentially the matrix $A$ in $B$, if that makes sense) reduce to the identity matrix?

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&\lambda_1'\\0&1&0&\lambda_2'\\0&0&1&\lambda_3' \end{pmatrix}$$

For some new where $\lambda'$s are scalar multiples of $\lambda$'s.

Comment: Yes, you seem correct! Since $\det \left( A \right) = 1 \neq 0$, the rank of $A$ must be $3$ and hence can be reduced to the identity matrix $I_3$ using elementary row transformations. However, $\lambda'$s are not only scalar multiplies of $\lambda$'s. They ($\lambda'$s) can be, more generally, linear combinations of $\lambda$'s.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Thanks! If I could ask a question that isn't even be related to the above necessarily, in similar matrices we have $A = P^{-1}DP.$ Does $P^{-1}DP= PDP^{-1}$? ($D$ is a diagonal matrix).